# How do I open a new terminal tab in my VScode extension? (split terminal)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a simple VScode extension which opens a number of terminal tabs and runs small snippets of code (to run dev server and client dev environment)

I would like to be able to open a new terminal in a terminal tab, in the same way that the 'split terminal' functionality works in the main editor

Currently I can create a new terminal using:

```
vscode.window.createTerminal(`New termainal name`)
```

However this creates a new terminal, whereas I would like to able to add a new tab to the current terminal in the same way as the 'Split terminal' button.

I am using the extension sample at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/terminal-sample/src/extension.ts

Thanks! M

Comment: Unfortunately the docs don't point to a solution for this, and despite split terminal appearing in the command palette, it's not an option in the complex commands docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api-commands I'd recommend opening an issue on github for this

Comment: Thanks - It looks like the feature is not yet available. The github issue is at : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45407

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is currently not supported, but planned:

[Add an API for splitting a terminal (#45407)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45407)